# ImageProcessor library library saving TIFF Group 4 as LZW

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, imageprocessor

I'm using the .NET imaging library ImageProcessor (http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/imagefactory/#methods)

When I read a TIFF file (1 bit CCITT group 4), and simply save it it's getting converted to a LZW 32bit tiff.

When I load the image (I think it uses system drawing library) the only option I have available is Format which already is TIFF.

Any idea how to keep it at this type of image? I suspect imageprocessor is just a wrapper on top of the built in .net library so it's Windows imaging library doing this.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/389) in the library affecting every version up to ImageProcessor 2.3.3

The fix will be deployed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks. I posted this before the bug was fixed :)

Comment: Yeah, I was just ensuring that there was an answer for other readers :)